# Parent last for Hibernate Arquillian test on JBOSS

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

I'm having an Arquillian test. The subject is an EJB that uses Hibernate 3, which I add to the shrinkwrapped archives along with all other Maven dependencies. It deploys the EJB as a JAR wrapped in an EAR, to an embedded JBOSS 7 which has Hibernate 4 on board. It clashes with the following exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.nullSafeSet(
    Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;Ljava/lang/Object;
    ILorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;)V
```

I strongly believe that my code (compiled against Hibernate 3) is executed against Hibernate 4, hence the error. JBOSS does parent first by default is my understanding, that would explain the error. I print out the archive contents as part of shrinkwrapping, so I believe I know Hibernate 3 is in the EAR.

I've tried changing JBOSS to parent last, but had no success at that. Some of these may be stupid, but I tried them anyway:

1. Added a `META-INF/jboss-classloading.xml` (to the JAR *and* the EAR)
2. Added a `META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` (to the JAR *and* the EAR) in attempt to exclude the parent Hibernate:
3. Delete the Hibernate JARs from JBOSS - that broke the server altogether

Following are a few configuration aspects of my setup:

- Dependencies:

  - `org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:provided`
  - `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.2.GA:provided`
  - `org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.1.1.Final:test`
  - `org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar:1.1.1.Final:test`
  - `org.jboss.as:jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed:jar:7.1.1.Final:provided`
  - `org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:jar:2.0.0:test`
  - `org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-web-6.0:pom:3.0.0.Final:provided`
- Pointing to an unpacked `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final`
- `META-INF/arquillian.xml`:

  ```
  <arquillian ...>
      <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />
      <container qualifier="jbossas-managed" default="true">
          <configuration>
          ...
          </configuration>
      </container>
  </arquillian>
  ```
- `META-INF/application.xml`:

  ```
  <application ...
     version="5">
     <module><ejb>test.jar</ejb></module>
  </application>
  ```

Anything else? :)

Your help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're packaging Hibernate 3 in your application, you should specify [the JPA provider as `hibernate3-bundled` in your persistence.xml file](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-PackagingtheHibernate3.5orgreater3.xJPApersistenceproviderwithyourapplication). Note that your current Hibernate 3.x version might not work and you may need to upgrade it to >= 3.5.

Or better use the Hibernate 4 JPA provider supplied by the container unless you have a reason to use Hibernate 3.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have been definitely *it*. On to the [next issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792304/parameter-value-element-did-not-match-expected-type-org-hibernate-type-en), it's a bumpy road!